# Djongo Boolean Filed get query is giving key error

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

i am using MongoDB(3.6) in Django(3.1.5) through djongo(1.3.3).

`models.py`

```
from djongo import models

class ModelClass(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
       is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

`view.py`

```
def model_class_view(request):
      obj = ModelClass.objects.get(name='name', is_active=True)
```

it is giving an error: `DatabaseError No exception message supplied`

Comment: Could you post the complete error message?

Comment: https://cdn.imageupload.workers.dev/fYYRzisu_MongoDBDatabaseError%20(1).png

Comment: I have the exact same problem Did you find a solution? I also have a boolean that crashes my entire project. Working with the newest django version and MongoDB. Any help yet? Cheers
PS same happens with all modifiers like `filter`, `exclude`, `get` etc

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and it is caused by Djongo not being able to filter for boolean fields correctly.

An issue was raised here https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/465
which also proposes a workaround.
So instead of `is_active=True` make it `is_active__in=[True]`

So try this:

```py
def model_class_view(request):
      obj = ModelClass.objects.get(name='name', is_active__in=[True])
```